# value not setting with '=' in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[image: Attached screenshot for the proof]I have a model which looks something like this:

```
class At::ModalityCombo < Base
  self.table_name = 'at_modalites_at_combos'

  belongs_to :at_modality, :class_name => 'At::Modality', foreign_key: :modality_id
  belongs_to :at_combo, :class_name => 'At::Combo', foreign_key: :combo_id

  attr_reader :modality_day
  attr_writer :modality_day
end
```

Migration for `modality_day` column is like:

```
class AddDayInModalityCombo < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    add_column :at_modalites_at_combos, :modality_day, :integer, default: 0
  end

  def down
    remove_column :at_modalites_at_combos, :modality_day
  end
end
```

On rails console,

```
abc = At::ModalityCombo.new
abc.modality_day = 4
abc
```

**Output:**

```
modality_id: nil, combo_id: nil, modality_day: 0
```

*Why modality_day is still 0?*

Comment: "modality_id is still 0" - it isn't.

Comment: Attached screenshot for the reference.

Comment: It looks like there's some conflation between `modality_id` and `modality_day` in your example screen shot and code. I'd suggest editing this post first to make it easier for us to help

Comment: Sorry, it was typo. I have edited it.

Comment: You're overwriting the Rails accessors for some reason.

Comment: @DaveNewton, where I can find it in the code?  Any suggestions?

Comment: @Bhawan ... where you set the reader and writer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confusing Rails here.

1. You have a column named `modality_day` on an Active Record model. This lets you read/write that property on instances of `At::ModalityCombo`.
2. You also have `attr_reader` and `attr_writer` setup for `modality_day`.

It looks like attr_writer/attr_reader is overriding the methods that would normally let you manage the property defined in your database. Deleting those should fix this and make it work like you expect.

---

`attr_reader :modality_day` is basically equivalent to:

```
def modality_day
  @modality_day
end
```

And `attr_writer :modality_day` is basically equivalent to:

```
def modality_day=(value)
  @modality_day = value
end
```

These methods manage an instance variable, but Active Record does not store your database data in this same way.

Answer (score 0):

`attr_reader`, `attr_writer` and `attr_accessor` should not be used in Rails models at all (at least not in Rails 5.0+). They are Rubys built in metaprogramming methods for creating setters and getters.

ActiveRecord actually reads the schema straight from the db and creates special setters and getters corresponding to the columns in the db table. These setters are light years from the basic `attr_writer` setter - they do type casting, dirty tracking etc.

If you use `attr_accessor` you overwrite the setter and your model will stop persisting the attribute among other things.

For "virtual attributes" that are not saved to the database use [the attributes api](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2018/12/11/rails-5-attributes-api.html) which does default values and typecasting.